# Having the document structure match the table of contents when using \include

Tags: table-of-contents, include, navigation, structure

[image]I'm a latex newbie and writing my thesis.
One of the things I really like about latex is that as I add sections chapters etc... it gets included in a navigable structure that can be used to browse the document.

In order to structure the over all document though while writing, I'm using smaller files for each chapter and then adding them in with the \include command. The table of contents is updated to match all the sections added in each chapter, but the navigable document structure that's output in the pdf does not match it and only shows the heading from the main.tex file.

How can I make the sections from the files that are imported with \include part of the main.tex file structure/ make the file structure match the table of contents?
Attached is a photo of how I would like the section heading back in t

Comment: Assuming that you mean the outline/bookmarks in the pdf viewer: it shouldn't matter if you use \include or not, but without a small example it is not possible to say what is wrong in your document.

Comment: Since \include forces a page break, it is normally only used with chapters.  You could use \input instead.

Comment: Thanks! I've just posted a photo of the problem. It seems that using \input or \include makes no difference.

Comment: Your problem seems to be a missing feature of your editor. What do you use? Texmaker does not support it, as far as I know.

Comment: Write now I’m using overleaf. Any suggestions on Mac based editors?

Comment: it was overleaf. I switch to texmaker and now it works fine. thanks!